# Insert value from PHP in HTML code on thank you page

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to get a value of order by PHP (in thank you page) and then use it in script as attribute (attribute v= in src link).

This is for Woocommerce

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'bbloomer_conversion_tracking_thank_you_page' );

function bbloomer_conversion_tracking_thank_you_page() {
?>
    <!-- Měřicí kód Sklik.cz -->
<iframe width="119" height="22" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="//c.imedia.cz/checkConversion?c=100056379&amp;color=ffffff&amp;v="></iframe>
<?php
}
```

I hoped that this code will work, but it doesnt.

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'bbloomer_conversion_tracking_thank_you_page' );

    function bbloomer_conversion_tracking_thank_you_page() {
    $price=$order->get_total();
?>
        <!-- Měřicí kód Sklik.cz -->
    <iframe width="119" height="22" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="//c.imedia.cz/checkConversion?c=100056379&amp;color=ffffff&amp;v=$price"></iframe>
    <?php
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/

```
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'bbloomer_conversion_tracking_thank_you_page');

function bbloomer_conversion_tracking_thank_you_page()
{
    echo '<!-- Měřicí kód Sklik.cz -->
    <iframe width="119" height="22" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="//c.imedia.cz/checkConversion?c=100056379&amp;color=ffffff&amp;v="></iframe>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Can you add more details, like the order number variable and where you want to insert.

A.S. as you add these details i will edit the answer or/and add a new answer.*

**Edit:**
You can't write php variables in a non-php script.
If you want to add a link, i suggest sing echo like this: this is your fixed code:

```php
    add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'bbloomer_conversion_tracking_thank_you_page' );

    function bbloomer_conversion_tracking_thank_you_page() {
    $price=$order->get_total();
?>
        <!-- Měřicí kód Sklik.cz -->
    <iframe width="119" height="22" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="//c.imedia.cz/checkConversion?c=100056379&amp;color=ffffff&amp;v=<?php echo $price ?>"></iframe>
    <?php
    }
```

---

## Enjoy your day!

Comment: I edited my question and add a code. I was thinking that this code will work but it does not. When you check it you will understand my intention. Thanks a lot.